# Image Intervention GD Driver getMimeType

Tags: php, image, laravel, intervention

I'm currently integrating Intervention Image to Laravel 4.2.
By doing the following, I get an error of "Command (getMimeType) is not available for driver (Gd)"

```
Image::make(Input::file($image_file))
```

How does this really works?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check in php.ini that was uncomment extension "php_fileinfo" or check in phpinfo().
2. Print in php script:

   ```
   print_r (gd_info());
   ```

   If you see:

   ```
   [GIF Read Support] => 0
   [GIF Create Support] => 0
   ```

   it can mean that you use old version extension specify above.