# Command (GetMimeType) is not available for driver (Gd)

Tags: laravel, file-upload, gd, image-resizing, intervention

I'm trying to use Intervention/Image library to resize my uploaded image file. but I'm getting this error:

```
"Command (GetMimeType) is not available for driver (Gd)."
```

when I checked with `print_r(gd_info())` this is the result:

```
Array ( 
  [GD Version] => bundled (2.1.0 compatible) 
  [FreeType Support] => 1 
  [FreeType Linkage] => with freetype 
  [GIF Read Support] => 1 
  [GIF Create Support] => 1 
  [JPEG Support] => 1 
  [PNG Support] => 1 
  [WBMP Support] => 1 
  [XPM Support] => 1 
  [XBM Support] => 1 
  [WebP Support] => 1 
  [BMP Support] => 1 
  [AVIF Support] => 1 
  [TGA Read Support] => 1 
  [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => 
)
```

according to [the answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29993307/1235167), they say it's the solution (like below)

[image: solution]

the file I uploaded was only 1280x960px (157KB), while the settings in my `php.ini` are like this:

```
memory_limit=512M
post_max_size=40M
upload_max_filesize=40M
```

so what am I missing? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello @dapidmini [helps](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php#87566)